# Why is the keyboard and cellphone / telephone numbers in a different order?

Tags: keyboards

Cellphone / Telephone have the seven bottom-left and the one top-left.

[image]

While the keyboard has the seven top-left and the one bottom-left

[image]

How did this come to be? Is there an interesting computing anecdote that gave rise to this?

Comment: If I had to guess, I wouldn't think it'd be that interesting. On a computer, the start is the bottom, since that's where your hand is. On the phone, you'd generally have been above one, so it makes sense to go top-down.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad doesn't say.  Perhaps the accepted answer should be edited in?

Comment: Question should be, why did the designers of the [Western Electric model 2500 telephone](https://www.oldphoneworks.com/2500-rose-beige.html) choose a layout that was different from the [10-key adding machines](http://branfordhouseantiques.com/cgi-bin/p/awtp-product.cgi?d=branford-house-antiques&item=10859) that were ubiquitous office equipment in the early 20th century? 'Cause those are the respective origins of the modern cell-phone layout and the modern numeric keypad layout.

Comment: This is a false dichotomy.  Those aren't the only two layouts in existence even in just computing.  This came up just recently at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15491/1932 as a matter of fact.  The terminal there, if one looks closely, has a numeric layout (on the blue keys) that is _neither_ of the ones in the question here, and is as mentioned one that could be found on several keyboards such as that of the Univac 1710.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad suggests Bell Labs did some studies on this in the 1950s and the telephone layout was the result. I am sure I have seen a better article on why the PC layout is reversed though.

Comment: This has also been asked and answered on several Stack Exchange sites now, including https://superuser.com/q/382640/38062 , https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/32885/42550 , and https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/16666/42550

Comment: Some banks in the UK have the cellphone arrangement on the outside and the computer keyboard arrangement on the inside.  I made the mistake of just remembering a pattern but not the number and took a while to figure out why the machine inside wouldn't accept my card but the one outside would.

Comment: @SolomonSlow No, the question should be what it is because most people wouldn't know the origins of the modern cell-phone layout and the modern numeric keypad layout. That's, presumably, why they're asking.

Comment: @user428517, Please accept my apoology for the less-than-genteel way in which I tried to direct the OP's attention to the retro roots of the question.

Comment: Only very recently has it been possible to place phone calls with a computer, and for only slightly longer has it been possibly to use a phone as a pocket calculator. The real question is why did touch tone phones not follow the calculator number layout?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

*(I got the feeling I've answered this already once, but can't find it)*

*(Also, this is meant as an overview, a timeline to see development and usage, not about any firsts, inventions or alike)*

### TL;DR:

Computer keyboards grew out of calculator key assignments, as both are business tools.

The telephone keypad arrangement was derived in an UI analysis in 1959/60 probing 'average' customers - people at the time not really in contact with calculators or even less computers.

---

### Calculators and Computers

Numeric ordering on a keyboard isn't as logical as someone might assume and went through several iterations. Early calculators used levers for each digit. This covers about the 1890s until 1920s (*1).

[image]

(From [ARITHMEUM](https://www.arithmeum.uni-bonn.de/sammlungen/rechnen-einst/objekt.html?tx_arithinventory%5Bobject%5D=1603) at University Bonn)

The next generation of calculators (and soon cash registers) used a set of columns, one per valid digit and 9 buttons per column (*2). Nine, as there was no need to enter a zero at all. All digits were  reset after each operation, and unlike when entering a number from a single keypad, no zero was needed to fill the gap. Almost like going back in time before the zero was invented. :)

This covers about the 1910s to 1930s.

[image]

(From [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brunsviga_90T_calculator_-_Ridai_Museum_of_Modern_Science,_Tokyo_-_DSC07647.JPG))

*(I selected this rather late Brunsviga 90T as it nicely demonstrates the use of other systems than decimal, as it's made for British ([pre-decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling#Decimalisation)) currency *3)*

While there were also some devices (especially cash registers) with numbers increasing from the top downwards, calculators usually placed the numbers bottom up, as they assumed the user to sit, having a hand movement coming from a rest point at the lower end (*4). Eye movement (to search) usually goes ahead of hand movement, so bottom-up gives the numbers in sequence.

This is especially neat to see with the following one, as the final function after entering a number will almost always be hitting the adding button which is located prominently in the lower right. The machine is special (as it is late) by having an extra row at the bottom. No, not for entering zero, but for resetting the column. Like any previous technology, it was based on a different way of thinking.

[image]

(From [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brunsviga_11S_calculator_-_Ridai_Museum_of_Modern_Science,_Tokyo_-_DSC07649.JPG))

When advanced mechanics allowed the use of a single keypad, the use case still stayed the same, resulting in a bottom up numbering, but now arranged in a square with a large zero or sometimes a double zero below. Keypad calculators became common place in the mid to late 1930s and lasted essentially until today ... well, no longer mechanical, but the UI is still the same.

[image]

(From [ARITHMEUM](https://www.arithmeum.uni-bonn.de/sammlungen/rechnen-einst/objekt.html?tx_arithinventory%5Bobject%5D=5036) at University Bonn)

This is where computers inherited it from. Except not right away. Early on during their own era, punch cards were simply numeric, with a top-down sequence. The sequence was mandated by the punch cards having their holes in the same order. Using any other order would need additional mechanisms, which is never a good idea. This is also why the numbers were not in rows but staggered. For example, IBM's Type 011 electric keypunch of 1923:

[image]

(Picture taken from the [fine computer historic page](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/oldpunch.html#ekpunch)s of Columbia University)

Notable that there is a digit zero, as punch cards do need zero key to actively punch a hole in row zero to represent `0`. :)

The first (IBM) alphanumeric keypunch, the Type 031, had a separate numeric keyboard, so operators could not only key in numbers fast, but also use that pad (as with prior machines) to enter characters as a combination of holes. To ease transition the keys were still staggered, even though it was no longer needed as punching was now done independently of the key position.

[image]

(Picture from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IBM_Type_31_keypunch_keyboard.agr.jpg), additional information here)

The IBM 026 keypunch of 1949 set the standard for the remainder of the punch card age as well as [early terminals](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15489) by dropping the numeric keypad - after all, who needs one if the highly sophisticated keypunch can do all punching on its own?

[image]

(Picture taken from the [fine computer historic page](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/026.html)s of Columbia University)

Now the keys are aligned within the alpha section, horizontally, but still semi-staggered through the key interleave. Important, the sequence was kept top down as with the Type 31, not changed to reassemble a calculators bottom up sequence.

IBM's early terminal system 2250/2260 as well as the new all changing 3270 family didn't feature numeric keypads (later 3270 variations did) so it was up to third party manufacturer to introduce such a splendid addition - like [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datapoint) did with the [Datapoint 2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datapoint_2200) (*5). They decided to start from scratch and make the numpad as found on calculators. This was not only because the assumed user would be in accounting rather than at an exchange, but push-button telephones had just been introduced a few years before and at the time they were still exotic, not available at all exchanges and in no way a prototype to be used - so calculators were the only serious template to follow.

[image]

(Taken from [this blog entry](https://bugbookmuseum.blogspot.com/2016/03/vintage-computers-datapoint-2200.html))

Well, computer-wise that's the end of the story.

---

Or not, as there is a nifty little piece of in-between: The ICL 1501, also known as Cogar 4 or Singer 1501 (*6). After ICL acquired the Singer computer division the 1501 was at the core of the system 10 and sold in good numbers. Since it was, like the Datapoint 2200, conceived as a data-entry system to replace key punches and simplify batch processing, its keyboard was styled after the 026 key punch. But, unlike CTC, they didn't add a numeric keypad; instead they stayed with the 026-style numeric field as part of the main field:

[image]

(Picture taken in storage at [Computeum](http://blog.computeum.org/2019/03/05/erstes-exponat-singer-icl1501/))

This machine was sold in Germany in the 1970s and used at a University. It features a US keyboard, and, as said, a 026-like numeric inset.  So far nothing special.

But then [Computeum](http://blog.computeum.org/2019/03/05/erstes-exponat-singer-icl1501/) got another unit, originally used by the State of Baden-Württemberg surveying service. Still with no separate numeric keypad, but the numeric keys flipped to match a calculator keyboard:

[image]

This keyboard is also of German layout, so it's hard to say if the change is due to the national keyboard (IBM didn't do it for their German 026), or because of new requirements (*7). Notable is that some of the very punch-card specific keys are completely gone (to make room for Umlauts).

---

### Telephones and Mobile Phones

The phone story is *quite* short and starts right after WWII with the idea of changing from pulse dial to tone dial to cut cost in exchanges by replacing all [Strowger switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strowger_switch) by [crossbar switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbar_switch#Electromechanical_switching_in_telephony). While crossbar switches had been in use since the 1930s, many exchanges still operated with Strowger switches. Going to [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) at the same time simplified it further by introducing electronics for line selection.

In 1959 Bell did a [rather large UI study](https://mrserge.lv/assets/human-factors-engeneering-studies-of-the-design-and-use-of-pushbutton-telephone-sets.pdf), published in 1960 as *"Human Factors Engineering Studies of the Design and Use of Pushbutton Telephone Sets"*. The goal was to determinate a layout that would not only work, but also operate efficiently and be enjoyed by users. They considered a great variety of layouts:

[image]

(Taken from [p999 of the publication](https://mrserge.lv/assets/human-factors-engeneering-studies-of-the-design-and-use-of-pushbutton-telephone-sets.pdf))

The square top-down layout emerged second, right after a two-row top-down version. Again, much like with cash registers vs calculators, it's due to the way a keyboard is scanned during interaction.

Long story short, since a two row design wouldn't fit great on a more squarish phone body (*8), the square 3 by 3 plus zero or 3 by 4 ordering with a top down scheme was it.

---

One might speculate that if calculators had been more widespread in the 1950s (they were special and expensive business tools at the time) or terminals/computers had already made their way into homes before, the telephone would also work bottom-up ... but that's fodder for alternate history novellas.

---

*1 - The dates are about when they were generally available and top end, not invention/first. Also, most designs were made and sold all through the mechanical age, including [Odhner style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odhner_Arithmometer) devices. Like always, industry is producing as long as customers are buying and there's a niche for every variation. Heck, even [Addiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addiator)s have been made way into the '80s when pocket calculators were already lower priced:))

*2 - It's noteworthy that Felt's [Compometer](https://www.arithmeum.uni-bonn.de/sammlungen/rechnen-einst/objekt.html?tx_arithinventory%5Bobject%5D=4597) already used key columns way before others, but it was an outlier at the time. It already had a bottom up ordering.

*3 - It may need a close look at display and key columns as the last column goes 1 to 11, while the third from the right only features the number 1 on all keys.

[British Pre-Decimal currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling#Decimalisation) was, like all Carolingian currency, structured as [LSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd) or 1 Librae (hence the £) to be split into 20 Solidi (s) each dividable into 12 Denari (d) or in English names 1 Pound equals 20 Shillings equals 240 Pence.

This is why the display, as well, is structured as  3-3-2-1:

- 3 digits for Thousands of Pounds,
- 3 digits for Pounds,
- 2 digits for Shillings (00..19), and
- 1 'digit' for Pence (0..11)

Sorry, no Farthings and no Guineas either. Bookkeeping was only done in pounds and full pence.

*4 - With cash registers the operator was assumed to stay.

*5 - The terminal that brought us x86 :))

*6 - The [Cogar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Cogar) 4 together with the Datapoint 2200 marks what I'd call the birth of the desktop PC. Both were complete machines that incorporated all elements of a standalone computer in one case: CPU, Memory, I/O, Screen (the C4 even bitmap graphic), keyboard and mass storage (tape drives).

*7 - So far I couldn't find any conclusive documentation/timeline, so it would be nice to find more examples to see if that change was due to adapting to new usage (switching to calculator style like others), specific German layout/requirement (some DIN) or customer/application specific.

*8 - Keep in mind, at the time the phone wasn't part of the receiver, but the receiver attached to the phone by cable :)

Comment: What an incredibly well researched answer. I am sorry that I can only upvote it once

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica You can give it a bounty...

Comment: "right after a two column top-down version" I think that must be "a two-row" version. p1001 says "the  arrangement with two vertical columns  of keys [...] was  disliked by many subjects", and in 3.2 they only study the 3x3+1 and two-row versions.

Comment: @muru row, column, papalapap .... :)) Of course you're right. Changed. Thanks for checking up the details.

Comment: Why were there no need to enter zeros in your second example? If you want to work with 20,52, you can't just ignore the middle zero, can you?

Comment: @d-b No, it can't be ignored, but it doesn't have to be entered either. Only 2 5 and 2 have to be pressed -there is no zero key (and no decimal key).

Comment: > _(I selected this rather late Brunsvga 90T as it nicely demonstrates the use of other systems than decimal, as it's made for English (pre decimal) currency)..._ "Yeah, but our numeric keypad goes up to eleven!" :)

Comment: @LouKnee I know that issue too well :)) Still not seeing the point. the shown machine goes as well up to 11 for the pence (last column) and up to 19 for shilling (2nd/3rd column from the right) don't let the whole row of 1s (3rd from right) fool you. That's also why the display is structured 3-3-2-1: 3-3 for pouds, 2 for shillings and 1 for pence - sorry, no fartlhngs and no guinees either. --- I guess I should add a foot note for non-Brits (and number system nerds).

Comment: It was just a simplistic joke (Spinal Tap reference). Presumably for 19' one would just press the "1" adjacent to the "9", and so there are 9 buttons identically labelled "1" that actually have different meanings.  I'm now also intrigued by the Type 031 having the numerals 2-0 on the top row, and only then the 1.

Comment: @LouKnee Oh .. cool; No, all 1's have the same meaning - as that digit really operated separately and only goes 0..1 (that is IIRC). The order at the 031 is strictly 0-1-2-3-4-5 and so on. Maybe look a little closer. The 0 is about the same amount above the 1 as the 1 is above the 2 - as this is exactly ~6.6 mm the punch card rows are sized vertically

Comment: I wasn't clear - I meant the top row of the alphanumeric keyboard on the 031. I get that typewriters of the time omitted the "1" as one could use the "I" instead, but it seems a bit poor that they bodged in all the new keys at the right-hand side of the 031 rather than shift the numerals across by one.

Comment: @LouKnee Oh, yes, sorry. I didn't read well as you wrote 'top row' which I associated with the num-pad That is an oddity. I would  like to think it's due some lever arrangement, but I not only have no 031, but as well never had the chance to look into one :(

Comment: Great answer. However, the alt text for all your images is _"enter image description here"_. Could you please follow that instruction so as to make your answer accessible? Furthermore, the images should be uploaded to the SE imgur (where permitted by licensing) so that they persist; this would also fix the one broken embed caused by a non-HTTPS target. Cheers :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Feel free to add descriptions - and if you're at it, tell me which picture you're referring to as not uploaded as well as which are broken (BTW,  HTTP is by default not broken but the way the web works)

Comment: @Raffzahn It is not possible to embed HTTP images in Stack Overflow answers, which I thought may be why you left the columbia.edu link as a simple hyperlink rather than being an image. The link text is "enter link description here", another instruction for you (not me!) to follow as the author of the answer. :) Thanks

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It might be helpful ii you would **exactly** point out where an issue is instead of assuming and giving unspecific descriptions - you may have noticed that it's a bit longer than a 3 line answer. That I only take when hired. Ofc, you may do so and instruct me. Basic rate is 235 EUR/h plus taxes, minimum 4 hours charged.

Comment: @Raffzahn I'm sorry for not being clear. For **every** image that you've posted, replace the text _"enter image description here"_ with a description of the image, to make your post accessible. Further, the link _"enter link description here"_ should be replaced by the image: you can use the upload mechanism of this site to pull the image into SE so that it can be embedded (you will get an error if you try to embed the current, HTTP, image). Then set an alt text for that too. I don't know how to say it in any other way, sorry. I thought I've been quite "specific" already. Cheers.

Comment: "The square top down layout emerged second, right after a two row top-down version"

This is a little confusing, do you mind adding in the actual groups shown in the image? (VI-A and IV-B, I assume?)

Comment: @godplusplus The embedded graphic is meant to show the highly variant layouts tested, not any renking - in so fat the footnotes are somewhat misleading. The ranking is shown and explained in the following page, so you might want to have a look inside the [PDF](https://mrserge.lv/assets/human-factors-engeneering-studies-of-the-design-and-use-of-pushbutton-telephone-sets.pdf) for this and any further detail

Comment: It is necessary to add image descriptions - see https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/276.  Note that if this site were hosted in the EU or UK, it would be illegal not to put in the image description under disability discrimination legislation.  The site must be capable of being rendered by browsers for the blind.  I suspect that it may be illegal in the USA under the ADA act but I'm not sure.  If anyone wishes to edit in the descriptions, please do so.

Comment: Joined this SE community just to push upvote.

Comment: I heard a long time ago that touch-tone phones were organized opposite to calculators in order to slow down fast touch-typers when dialing because the early switches couldn't keep up.  This answer pretty much summarily debunks that idea.  Neat!

Comment: I guess an important reason for calculators to have smaller digits nearer to the user is that the smaller digits are more common in actual numbers (representing quantities), whereas telephone numbers are more evenly distributed.  Is there any evidence that this was a factor?

Comment: @TobySpeight Not really, as soon as numbers have multi digits, and digit is about as common. There are rarely single digit numbers. It's really more about the way accountants work - think of a sheet of paper with items and then moving your sight u to the machine to enter them. Low first brings them in natural order (likewise, just the other way around for cashiers as they are standing - like still in the US - communicating with the customer). For phones the decision making is well documented in the linked paper.

Comment: "Sorry, no Farthings and no Guineas either. Bookkeeping was only done in pounds and full pence." My dad definitely has a mechanical calculator that has at least ha'penny resolution, possibly even farthing, I don't recall.

Comment: @Muzer Sure, much likely a calculator used in sales, likewise there are tills (cash registers) with half/quarter penny, as it's about summing up items for (small) sales (in fact the only one I've ever seen uses a single digit with keys marked 1/4, 2/3, 3/4) . Broken pence had already lost their practical value in the early 1900s, not changed by the deflation of the 1920. Their use was psychological pricing, much like today's .5 or .9 penny ending of petrol prices. In accounting (and ultimate taxation) fractions of a penny was not a thing - at least not by any standard.

Answer (score 20):

Both keypads are in numerical order.  However, in a computing context, the correct order is 0,1…9, but in a telephonic context, the correct order is 1…9,0 - because the latter is really a ten, not a zero.

To explain this, we have to go back about a century, to the days when both telephones and computing devices were electromechanical rather than purely electronic.  Here are typical devices from each class of that time:

[image: A mechanical desk calculator]
[image: A vintage rotary-dial telephone]

A mechanical calculator has a mechanism for each digit that engages zero times per handle rotation when the "zero" (blank) button has been pressed, one time when the "one" button has been pressed, and so on up to nine.  This makes complete sense in an arithmetic context, and allows the device to be used as a fast, user-friendly abacus.  The more sophisticated models (not the one pictured) can even multiply and divide by themselves.

A rotary-dial telephone, on the other hand, has a mechanism which pulses the line once when the dial is released from the "one" position, twice when from the "two" position - and ten times from the "zero" position.  These pulses were interpreted by an electromechanical selector in the exchange.  This is why zero is commonly used as the "escape code" for long-distance and international dialling; it was convenient to hang the cabling to the trunk exchange off the last position of each local selector.

Computer numerical keypads were designed through decades of evolution to handle arithmetical data conveniently, much as the rest of the keyboard was designed to retain familiarity with teletype and mechanical typewriter equipment.  But a phone keypad is not designed for arithmetic; it was designed for people familiar with a rotary-dial telephone, in which zero is adjacent to nine, and continues to remain in that de-facto standard layout.

Comment: There were/are (at least) two pulse-dial standards. One is "dial n pulses for any n!=0, 0 is 10" and the other is "dial n+1 pulses for n, 0 is 0".

Comment: Re, "in a telephonic context,... [the "0"] is really a ten," Saying that the "0" was _encoded_ as ten pulses during the rotary-dial era is not the same thing as saying what the "0" _is really_.  The "0" is really a _symbol_ that can by transmitted however we choose to transmit it in any given system, and when it is received at the other end, its meaning is whatever we choose it to mean in a given context.

Comment: @Vatine The ten pulses for zero convention was used throughout Europe and North America, where the DTMF standard (introducing the phone keypad) was designed.  If another convention was used elsewhere in the world, that had no influence on the question being asked here.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sure, and the `#` and `*` symbols could be called "eleven" and "twelve", if they were so encoded into pulse-dialling.  But they are specific to DTMF, and arose as an accident of the latter's design as a 3x4 matrix.  In the pulse-dialling system, the zero functionally *was* a ten, based on the number of pulses sent and its resulting position on the dial.

Comment: For sure Sweden used the n+1 system, so definitely not all of Europe. This was... interesting when people started importing cooler-looking phones from abroad in the 80s.

Comment: As someone else wrote : in sweden, the phones coded 0 as 1 pulse, 1 2 pulses etc. The coding was done by the mechanics in "petmojen".

Comment: DTMF is, and always was, a 4x4 matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling The fourth column symbols, "A," "B," "C," and "D," originally were meant to be present on consumer equipment, to be used for navigating computerized menu systems; but they ultimately were left off as a cost-saving measure. Those symbols have been sporadically used for internal signalling within the public phone system, and they have also been used in other applications. DTMF chips typically can generate and/or decode all 16 symbols.

Comment: P.S., When My parents taught me to recite my phone "number" when I was growing up, it was "Mitchell-6, 9188." Anyone in my town would have known to dial "MI" for the "Mitchell" part. Six pulses stands for "6," but six pulses can also stand for "M," and four pulses can stand for "I." That's the _original_ reason why phone dials were marked with numbers _and_ letters. The fact is, phone "numbers" never were _numbers_.  They're just _strings_ of symbols.

Comment: This explains why 0 is adjacent to 9 on a phone but is adjacent to 1 on a computer, but doesn't explain the bottom-to-top orientation of a computer number pad - you could just as easily copy the top-to-bottom orientation of a telephone dial pad, and just put the 0 at the top. I suspect there might be a Benford's Law element that makes inputting numbers into a computer generally more efficient if the lower-numbered keys are closer to the user. Otherwise, why reorient the whole number pad instead of just moving the 0?

Comment: @NuclearWang If you look at the two devices above, you'll see that the zero is in the lowest position in both cases, which happens to match the modern situation.  My point is that the two layouts were developed independently; there is no sense of taking one layout and changing it into the other one.

Comment: @Chromatix Good point, if the devices developed independently there would be no copying from one to another. But even if developed separately, it's interesting that UI research settled on opposite solutions for a computer vs a phone. For relatively light use of dialing phone numbers, following a top-down reading order is best for the casual user, but for repeated keying of sums and arbitrary numbers, the bottom-up reaching order is best for those with computer expertise.

Answer (score 14):

To add to the confusion, here's a photo of the bottom of my [Ericofon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ericofon)

[image]

In New Zealand the 1 to 9 digits on a rotary dial are backwards compared to other countries. Dialing '9' produces 1 pulse, '8' is 2 pulses etc. until '0' which is the usual 10 pulses.

But what does this have to with computer and phone keypads? With a rotary dial the further the dial is rotated the more pulses it produces, so the higher (or in NZ lower) digits take longer to dial. Therefore it makes sense to allocate telephone numbers starting from lower digits because those numbers can be dialed faster (except in New Zealand!). With the lower digits being more common and requiring less hand movement, the finger naturally settles towards the top of the dial. Digital keypads also followed this arrangement because people were used to seeing the lower digits at the top.

With computer keyboards the hands normally rest at the bottom/front of the keyboard, so the lower digits are faster to type. The reason for putting them there is similar in that the frequency of real-world numbers tends to favor smaller first digits ([Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)) ie.'1's are more prevalent than '9's. So it makes sense to have the lower digits at the bottom of the keyboard, closer to the operator. This is also why the '0' key is often made bigger, since it gets typed more often.

Comment: What a beauty (as well as the Aquarius). The flipped NZ dialling did escape me until now. More useless knowledge! Thanks :))

Comment: Even later numeric pad phones were not entirely consistent.  I remember my niece visiting from Denmark and complaining that our UK phones had the numbers the wrong way round.  I cannot remember which way around ours were but apparently it was the opposite to Denmark. This would have been mid to late 1980s.

Comment: Of course it is - Everything is upside down in New Zealand ;)

Comment: That's the reason the standard (international) emergency number is 112 (111 would be shorter, but that wasn't used because it's too susceptible to be dialled by line noise).

Comment: The emergency number was in the case of Sweden 90000 ie 9 (the farthest number) and at least 4 of the closest one (0)   The exchange didn't care if the dialer dialed 4 or 40 zeroes.

Answer (score 9):

There is a story, probably apocryphal, that there was a meeting, back in the day, between some ATT folks and some TI folks.

ATT asked, "How did you guys come up with that layout? We did a ton of human factors stufies and focus group testing, and the top-to-bottom keypad clearly out-performed the bottom-to-top, in both efficiency and user preference.  What did you find?"

The TI folks looked blankly back at the ATTers, "Studies?"

Answer (score 7):

The numeric keypad key order is derived from cash registers keyboards. Example of keyboard from a Sharp cash register (but they're all following this order):

[image]

Numeric keypads are/were used by accountants on computers to enter digits. They probably didn't want to force those people to change their typing habits when migrating from cash registers to computers.

When the cellphones came out, they copied the digit order from landline phones with keys, where the aim of the keyboard was to type phone numbers. The ones who designed the first phone keypads (not the ones who invented cellphones!), they probably disregarded the keypad order and reorganized it more logically with following digits.

They kept the 0 below, though.

Comment: The 0 was below because it was adjacent to the 9 on a rotary-dial telephone.

Answer (score 3):

There is a factoid @Raffzahn somehow left out of his exceptional answer.  AT&T's Touch-Tone (aka Dual Tone Multi-Frequency Signaling, DTMF) specification contains a larger set of values than is commonly used.  Envisioning up to a 4x4 array of values, they planned for something like:

[image: 4x4 array of Touch-Tone keypad]

Thinking ahead, they thought phones might take advantage of computer connections. The four letter keys might activate menus -- pretty forward-thinking for a 1960 design.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling

Me? I'm ready for hexadecimal dialing!

Comment: :)) There are quite a few more details left out, as well about calculators and computer keyboards, except they do not really add to the answer or are not really related to the question. For the 1633 column (A..D) for example that they are not only natural due the math behind assignment, but as well being quite at the edge of usable bandwith. They were considered only safe within a customer side exchange for local functions. (Oh, and BTW, A..D are still supported by GSM record formats :))

Comment: Also notable that many digital door locks include the * and # keys, but otherwise usually follow the telephone convention.